# Linux Mint: how to update repository references

Tags: linux-mint

I have a Linux Mint 10 Julia installed on my machine.

I'd like to upgrade, but as Linux Mint upgrade page says: why upgrade? I would like to upgrade in order to have more recent software and fixes.

According to that my intent is to update repository references so that I can benefit of newest updates and fixes for my installed packages.

Which is the most appropriate way to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred method is the following:

1. Making a backup of the data
2. Making a backup of the software selection
3. Performing a fresh installation using the liveCD/liveUSB of the new release
4. Restoring the data
5. Restoring the software selection

That way you have the greatest chance of getting a new working system. More detailled information can be found on this blog post: [How to upgrade to a newer release](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2)

Since you probably want to upgrade to version 13, a version with long term support, I would not recommend updating the package repository entries in `sources.list`. You could have tried that from one version to the next. But from version 10 to 13 there's too much that changed inbetween.

Comment: So you would suggest a "fresh" upgrade. Ok. My only concern is about my actual BugZilla installation which already holds hundreds of bugs that I must keep track of. So first I need to learn how to backup that installation and how to restore it elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know bugzilla. User data is only stored in `$HOME`, since that's the only permanent place where the users have write access to. Database systems might also store data in `/var/cache`, `/usr/local/` or also `/var/lib`. Such data needs to be saved with a database dump, copying the binary database blobs is not necessarily portable.

Comment: @BerserkEVA Mint is oriented towards desktop users who only have data in their home directory. Calling reinstalling “fresh upgrades” is a bit of a joke. If you're making nontrivial use of your Linux installation, I recommend using a distribution that takes upgrades seriously, for example Ubuntu.

Comment: @Gilles Mint is based on Ubuntu and almost everything that applies to Ubuntu concerning updates applies to Mint as well. I don't see what makes Mint “less serious” than Ubuntu. I don't know of any distribution that supports an upgrade skipping two versions. If you don't like reinstalls go for a distribution that uses a *rolling release cycle*, e.g. Debian testing/sid or Arch.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://blog.whatgeek.com.pt/2011/12/upgrade-linux-mint-11-katya-version-12-lisa/) has some info on what in `/etc/apt/sources*` need to be changed to enable the possibility of dist-upgrading.

Though I'm seeing red flags on many links that indicate it can break the system instead of completing successfully.  This would necessitate a full reinstall, where the "preferred" upgrade method is to do a reinstall in the first place.

So long as your `/home` is on a separate partition from `/` I recommend just doing a reinstall.

Comment: You should consider to use more descriptive descriptions for the links. [Upgrade Linux Mint 11 to version 12](http://blog.whatgeek.com.pt/2011/12/upgrade-linux-mint-11-katya-version-12-lisa/), for instance, would have been a much better link description. Furthermore, links can expire. It would be better if you had copied the instructions into your answer (since it's just a few lines) and keep the link as the source.

Comment: @Marco I'll try to do more like that in the future.  But the linked page had so much, I wasn't sure what really was necessary, and what wasn't.  Also, from several results I found, the "failure possible/likely, reinstall recommended" thing seemed the strongest point needing to be conveyed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is generic information for upgrade a debian based distro:

1. Update `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the new version's repository.
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get dist-upgrade`

You should do independent research on how to update your sources file(s).
I found this though:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ maya main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free

#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games
```